# variable showed as undefined because of some javascript Hoisting

Tags: javascript, html, json, hoisting

**EDIT: Ok i got the problem. the #t01 ID is not accessible inside the ajax success function so there is nothing getting displayed. Its something called as javascript hoisting. But i didnt find a way to tackle this problem. When i put document.getElementById('t01').innerHTML = content outside the ajax statement i get *undefined* being displayed**

I'm not able to get json returned from php to be displayed in my html. I'm not sure, where I'm going wrong.

**index.html**

```
 <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady() {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
    function onSuccess(position) {
    var lat,lon,content;
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');

        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude  + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
    lat= position.coords.latitude;
    lon= position.coords.longitude;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php", 
    data:{lat:lat , lon:lon},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response){
    content = "<ul>";
    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var i in parsed){
    content += "<li>" + parsed[i].ClassName+" "+ parsed[i].City+"</li>";
    document.getElementById('t01').innerHTML = content;
    }
}
});
});

}
 function onError(error) {
 alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
       'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
 }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
    <div id="t01"> </div>   </body>
```

**PHP code**

```
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
    $lat = $_GET['lat'];
    $lon = $_GET['lon'];
$var= array();
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"//all the query goes here//") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
    $var[]=$row;
    }
echo '{"college":'.json_encode($var).'}';
mysqli_close($con);
```

**JSON response**

```
'[{"ID":"1","ClassName":"somaiya","City":"mumbai","latitude":"19.073507000000","longitude":"72.899545000000","distance":"1.04906981264925"}]'
```

I'm getting the data from mysql to php and from php is getting encoded to json and sent to html, but it is not getting displayed in html.

Comment: have you looked on network debug on your browser to see if it's valid json?

Comment: have you tried this var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(response); . inside your success ajax?

Comment: @ArunBS nope i have not tried that. just new to json stuff. can u help me on the proper syntax according to my code for parseJSON

Comment: How is angularjs related to this question?

Comment: Actually This is just part of code. Rest of the Project is on angularjs. Maybe in some way angularjs might be creating problem so added the angularjs tag

Comment: Where in your JSON response is the {"college:" that you echoed in your php gone?

Comment: @mainguy i edited some code. Just forgot to include it .... I will update it up

Comment: @Chetan Shah Have you managed to make this work yet?

Comment: no not yet!!! Searched the whole Stack Overflow For this

Comment: Hmm, works for me in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zBNb9ivEe59PNEjNSdcD?p=preview (Of course not with a real ajax call) Maybe you overwrite the html of #t01 at some later point again? ps: added a closing bracket to the json.

Comment: I dont understand why it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this...

```
echo '{"college":'.json_encode($var).'}';
```

and replace it with

```
 return json_encode($var);
```

Either do that....or change your ajax success to something like this...

```
  success: function(response)
    { 
      ver dat = response.college;
    $('#t01').html(dat.ID);

    }
```

Comment: Well none of this "response":"connected<br>{\"college\":[{\"0\ is valid JSON, so I dont know what youre actually trying to do.  But what I show, is that you have to access what youre sending via the college tag, since thats where its encapsulated, or remove it althogether.  Wether your json actually works and is valid or not, is upt to you.

Comment: i updated the response . edited the code and getting the response now in proper format

Answer (score 0):

First thing The function **json_encode** needs PHP >= 5.2

Your PHP

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"//all the query goes here//");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
}
return json_encode($rows);
```

Your AJAX

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                
   url: "http://geolocation.webatu.com/Radius.php",
   data:{lat:lat , lon:lon},
   success: function(response) {
        var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        $('#t01').html(objData );
   }
```

Just using jquery.parseJSON inside success. which will give you [object object]. You have to use objData.ID or something u wanted. I am not sure this will completely work. Modify the code as needed.

Comment: Didnt work :( Thanks for your time. any more suggesion

Comment: your php code and ajax code are in different pages rite?

Comment: yupp. PHP is uploaded on web hosting site. AJAX is in mobile. Its a cordova application

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the Content-Type header:

```
<?php
    $var = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

You can verify the encoded json string by directly typing the url of your script on browser.
Then you can get the data as object through your JavaScript/

Comment: well there is ambiguity what you have shared in your answer you have this code

 $(document).ready(function(){   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "server.php", 
    data:{lat:lat , lon:lon},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response){
    content = "<ul>";
    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var i in parsed){
    content += "<li>" + parsed[i].ClassName+" "+ parsed[i].City+"</li>";
    document.getElementById('t01').innerHTML = content;
    }
}
});

with in the function due to it never get the chance to execute it self

Answer (score 0):

In index.html you have `success: function(response)` and `var college = data.college`.  Change this to `var college = response.college`.

Comment: changed it. Forgot to edit it over there !! Still Didnt work .. thanks for your time